# Can 3 distinct, non-parallel planes form 3 distinct, parallel intersection lines?

Tags: geometry

Consider 3 distinct, non-parallel planes. Each pair of planes intersect at an intersection line, thus forming 3 intersection lines (which may or may not be distinct and which may or many be parallel).

My question is this: Can the 3 intersection lines be distinct and parallel?

If not, how would one prove this?

Comment: Yes. Easily. Draw a triangle in a plane $\Pi$ and take a plane perpendicular to $\Pi$ through each side of the triangle. Then the three lines of intersection are all perpendicular to $\Pi$, one through each vertex of the triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Take the following planes:

$z=0$, $y=1$ and $y=z$.

They intersect forming the lines:

$(x,1,0)$, $(x,0,0)$, and $(x,1,1)$ which are all distincts and parallel.